# Append form to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been tasked with creating a dynamic `form` using jQuery. Once I have created the form I need to send the form to a `div` tag declared in the `body`. I am under no circumstances allowed to declare the form in the body of the HTML. The form is created in the script and displayed in the body.

```
var frm = $("<form id=searchform></form>");     
$("#searchform").append(txt4, txt3, txt5, txt6); // txt4 etc, are elements added to the form    
$("#reports2").html("#searchform");// SOMETHING NOT QUITE RIGHT HERE!
```

`reports2` is declared as a div in the body, code above is in a script locally. Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide the `frm` variable to the `append()` method, not the string selector for the element which is not yet in the DOM, and not to the `html()` method as that expects a string. Try this:

```
var $frm = $("<form id=searchform></form>");
$frm.append(txt4, txt3, txt5, txt6);
$("#reports2").append($frm);
```

Or alternatively:

```
var $frm = $('<form id="searchform"></form>');
$frm.append(txt4, txt3, txt5, txt6).appendTo('#reports2');
```

Both of the above are logically the same, the latter is just shorter due to the chained method calls. Note the `$` before the variable name is a naming convention used to denote that the variable holds a jQuery object.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? You may be best to start a new question if you have further issues.